# Node.js file download gets truncated by "require" statement

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to download and require a .js file using a node.js script, but only part of the file is being downloaded.

Specifically, this is the part that seems to be causing the problem:

```
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    out.write(chunk);
    var theModule = require(__dirname + "/" + filename);
    //less than half of the file is downloaded when the above line is included.
});
```

Here is the full source code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

downloadModule("functionChecker.js");

function downloadModule(filename) {
    var google = http.createClient(80, 'www.google.com');
    var request = google.request('GET', '/svn/' + filename, {
        'host': 'javascript-modules.googlecode.com'
    });
    request.end();
    out = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    request.on('response', function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            out.write(chunk);
            var theModule = require(__dirname + "/" + filename);
            //less than half of the file is downloaded when the above line is included.
            //If the import statement is omitted, then the file is downloaded normally.
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems that the downloading of the file is being interrupted by the "require" function, and the file is truncated before it is entirely downloaded. I still haven't figured out how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` event can be called multiple times. You need to wait until all of the data is written.

```
response.setEncoding('utf8');
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    out.write(chunk);
});
response.on('end', function(){
    out.end();
    var theModule = require(__dirname + "/" + filename);
});
```

Also, `createClient` is deprecated, as mentioned in [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createclient_port_host). I'd also recommend using `pipe` to simplify your logic.

```
function downloadModule(filename) {
  http.get({
    hostname: 'javascript-modules.googlecode.com',
    path: '/svn/' + filename
  }, function(res){
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    out.on('close', function(){
      var theModule = require(__dirname + "/" + filename);
    });

    res.pipe(out);
  });
}
```

Comment: What does the `pipe` function do here?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Docs are here: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options

Comment: Is there a way to download files synchronously, instead of asynchronously (as shown here)?

Comment: Node's network APIs are all asynchronous, so this is not possible without writing your own underlying C++ APIs that would work synchronously.

Comment: Using this code I sometimes get incomplete https downloads, always the same size, but incomplete. What could be the reason for that? Note: the server does not send a Content-Length with its response. Maybe `pipe` cannot handle that properly then?